# beanplot change order of items in legend

Tags: r, legend

I'm using the beanplot function from the beanplot package, and I am wanting to change the order of my items on my x axis.

My code looks like this:

```
beanplot(NoEggs~Treat, data=data, col=list("firebrick", "deepskyblue3", "chartreuse4"),
     ylab="Number of eggs", xlab="Reproductive mode",
      las=1, ylim=c(0,140), cutmin = 1.1, cutmax =99)
```

[Here is the graph I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKOLe.png)

I need to make Pa as the first one, then Mo and Po. How do I do that?

Comment: `data$Treat <- factor(data$Treat, levels = c("Pa", "Mo", "Po"))`

Comment: Yuss! Thank you!!!